# Cannot find java.lang.object class error even though java(jre6) is installed properly

Tags: java, class, object

I have a web project in java(struts based). I have imported the project in a workspace(not created) and trying to compile it. But it is giving error "cannot find class java.lang.object". Also, I noticed this project does not have jre system libraries folder. I have other projects also in the same workspace, all are working fine. Please suggest

Comment: Please state the name of your IDE. Is it Eclipse? Netbeans?

Comment: Have you chosen a JRE for your project in the build settings?

Comment: The project might reference a specific JRE which is not available. Go to the build path and fix it.

Comment: It should be `Object` with a capital O.

Comment: IDE is RAD. The project I am using is created on some one else's system. I am analysing the project.

Comment: I find it curious that you say "JRE6 is installed properly", but it takes a JDK to compile Java programs in general.  I'm even more curious that you assert it is installed properly, but you post your question here asking for other people's help.

Comment: sorry if I am wrong here. I am not able to find jre system library in libraries tab of build path so that I can change it. The documentation for this project suggests, it should be built in java1.6 compiler. I checked on my system its jre6. Please suggest what else I can check.

Comment: "jre6 is installed properly" I can say this because all other imported projects in the same workspace is running fine. Only issue is with this project. Even I am curious to know the reason

Comment: @Aarav If there's no JRE system library, add one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To fix this issue follow these steps

1. Right click > Properties > Build Path.
2. Find the "JRE System Library" in the list (if this is missing then this error message is not an eclipse bug but a mis-configured project).
3. Remove the "JRE System Library.
4. "Add Library ...", Select "JRE System Library" and add the appropriate JRE for the project (eg. 'Workspace default JRE').
5. Click "Finish" and rebuild the application

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the JRE is configured for the previous workspace and you'll need to configure it again (unless there's no JRE at all). The paths might differ between development environments.

Since RAD is based on Eclipse I assume the same logic applies there:

*Right Click on project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > JRE System Library*

It should appear as *Unbound*, if I'm not mistaken. Remove it and add the correct one. If it does not appear, add it altogether:

*Add Library > JRE System Library*

Note: I assume the `java.lang.object` is actually just a typo of `java.lang.Object`, given that you're analyzing an existing project and the problem is quite particular.

Comment: I have one more issue in the same project. Some libraries are showing unbounded. One is WAS_50_PLUGINDIR/lib/j2ee.jar. What is the meaning of this.

Comment: @Aarav Unbound = not found. *WAS_50_PLUGINDIR* seems like a path variable. You should configure it as well.